# R tm - how to get sparsity of TermDocumentMatrix as a variable?

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I have several large TermDocumentMatrices, which I'm trimming down to a more manageable size using the `removeSparseTerms()` function. One of the arguments I have to send this, of course, is `sparse`.

Because the TDMs are all quite different, I'd like to be able to base the value I pass to `sparse` on some measure of their sparsity. I can see this measure using the `inspect()` function, but for the life of me I can't find a way to extract this from the metadata. Is there a suitable function in `tm` that I just haven't found?

Comment: Sparsity is the number of zero-valued elements over the total number of elements in the matrix, so you can get it using `1-length(M$v)/(nrow(M)*ncol(M))`.

Comment: If you look at the source code of `tm:::print.TermDocumentMatrix`, you can see that the actual formula is `round((1 - length(x$v)/prod(dim(x))) * 100)` (which is essentially the same thing).

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!